# Python Dictionary for loop None Value

Tags: python, dictionary

My code:

```
hand = {'e': 1, 'i': 2, 'h': 1, 's': 1, 'r': 1, 'w': 1, 'v': 2}
def showhand(a):
    for letter in hand:
        for j in range(hand[letter]):
            print letter,
```

The output I'm expecting to get is:

```
e i i h s r w v v
```

But what I see is:

```
e i i h s r w v v None
```

I do not know where the `None` value comes from. How do I get the output I want?

Answer (score 7):

You must be calling the function like this:

```
print showhand(...)
```

Doing so causes Python to print the return value of `showhand`, which is `None`.

To fix your problem, remove the `print` and call your function like so:

```
showhand(...)
```